# RabbitMQ & MQTT : how to alert a third party of non consumed messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I am using RabbitMQ with the MQTT plugin, with both producer and consumer on QoS=1.
I am still very new to RabbitMQ so I would like to understand if there is a way/efficient pattern to ensure a fallback in case a consumer is not consuming the messages of the topic he has subscribed to.

For instance, the idea being to be able to send an alert to a server trigger another channel (email, push notification) after a few seconds if a client is not consuming the messages of the MQTT topic?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [per-message](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats) or [per-queue](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-queue-message-ttl) TTL and then catch expired messages with the help of [Dead Letter Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) extension. That will act as a notification of stalled or slow consumer or no consumers at all.

Comment: how does that actually works for MQTT topic? how do I setup the DLX for 10 clients, and be sure to only queue messages for the clients that don't consume it?

Comment: MQTT works on top of AMQP base in RabbitMQ implementation, so what I wrote may works for you, but it really depends of how you use MQTT. You can pre-create queues with TTL and DLX settings pre-set and use it from MQTT. Then create some emergency queue and bind it to DLX and also use it from MQTT to get expired messages. Alternatively, if you create queues in runtime, you can use policies for setting TTL and DLX. Actually, it doesn't matter will you use it from MQTT or AMQP, I just giving the brief idea.